# Filter on content_object django comments

Tags: python, django

I have this simple model of a Video

```
class Video(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField()
    active = models.BooleanField()
```

Currently I filter for all comments on a video like this.

```
comments = Comment.objects.for_model(Video)
```

This there an easy way to exclude where Video "active" is false on this queryset.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could filter on the `object_pk` of the comment. Just make sure it is in the list of active video ids. For example:

```
active_videos_ids = Video.objects.filter(active=True).values_list('id', flat=True)
comments = Comment.objects.for_model(Video).filter(object_pk__in=active_videos_ids)
```

I've never actually used the comments app before, so let me know if you have any problems with this, and I will dig into it.